# CSVWriter will not take ArrayList Convert to Array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist

I would like to export a multidimensional array to a CSV file. I'm able to get a set array to export, but am struggling with a growing array

Here is what I have so far:

```
String[][] data = new String[][] {
    new String[]{"quick","brown","fox"},
    new String[]{"apple","banana","cherry"},
    new String[]{"quick","brown","fox"}
};

for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        //first line prints "quick", "brown", "fox" etc
            writer.writeNext(data[i]);
        }
```

Now growing from my code, I need to be able to add arrays to "data".

For instance, if I have:

```
String[] abc = new String[] {"a","b","c"};
String[] def = new String[] {"d","e","f"};
...
```

and I don't know how many of these string arrays I'll have, researching tells me that I'll need to add these to a ArrayList. So I came up with something like this:

```
        List<String[]> stockList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        stockList.add(abc);
        stockList.add(def);
        // could potentially add more

        String[] stockArr = new String[stockList.size()];
        stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);

        for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            writer.writeNext(stockArr[i]);
            Log.i("loop", "here: " + data[i]);
        }
```

except writeNext cannot be applied to a java string.

Overall, it seems like I need to have an ArrayList of a string arrays. Then at the end, convert that ArrayList into an Array and not lose the string arrays?

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
for(String[] arr:stockList) {
    writer.writeNext(arr);
    Log.i("loop", "here: " + arr);
}
```

Better still :

`writer.writeAll(stockList);`